# Clojure compilation

Tags: clojure, compilation

I have a problem with clojure compilation: when i used the "(compile app.clj)" function in the cmd.exe(executed in the main folder of clojure) on windows and in the terminal(in the home directory, clojure installed from ubuntu software center) in linux- clojure throw the classnotfoundexception and doesn't found the source when it was ready with the required settings. Please, somebody help me for setup the compilation. Thanks!

Comment: By far your best plan is to use Leiningen when compiling and running Clojure. If it isn't working for you, ask a separate question with that problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not using compile function properly.
[Documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/compile) clearly states that parameter must be a namespace symbol. I do not know namespace of app.clj, but it should look like *my-project.app*. Therefore correct call would be something like:

```
(compile 'my-project.app)
```

There might also be other problems (like not defining proper classpath), but they can be easily resolved using [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/). If you are not using it already, you definitely should.

Comment: Hello! Thanks, but i tried this, but this isn't the solution of my problem. I already read the documentation and that doesn't work. The result when i use this:"FileNotFoundException Could not locate myp/app/clj__init.class or myp/app/clj.clj" and when i set the folder tree to "myp/app/clj.clj", clojure print:"FileNotFoundException Could not locate app.clj...".

Comment: When i set the folder tree to "myp/app/clj.clj", clojure print:"FileNotFoundException Could not locate app.clj...". When i want to use leiningen, print "Leiningen missing its dependencies. Please see "Building" in the README." And there is no insteresting thing for the solution. I haven't had it so far worry about compilation with many languages i tried.

Comment: @user1995302, seems like a classpath problem to me.

Comment: Like I wrote before, Leiningen manages that for you most of the time. If you use Ubuntu (or any other Debian based Linux for that matter) try installing it with apt-get (sudo apt-get install leiningen in terminal). After that just create new project with lein new project_name and put source file in src/project_name/. Only make sure that namespace corresponds to path. It might be a little tricky.

Comment: BTW. compilation is not really necessary to develop applications in Clojure. If you want to generate stand alone application just package project into jar by using lein uberjar, and then use it as any other Java jar app.

Comment: Hi, the leiningen package doesn't exist, but the classpath problem and the uberjar is interesting to me. I don't know any people who use clojure. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: And i put the project into 'home' folder, what is the default folder for terminal. May be wrong?